# Open Excel file spontaneously changes to read-only

Tags: ms-office

I have an Excel file that I have to update 2-3 times a week. Due to the volume of work I do inside the file, it is often open for several hours at a time. I am often able to save the file with no issue, but periodically I find that something has happened to make the file read-only I cannot save it after hours of work.

How can I prevent Excel from changing my file to read-only?

Please note that this is not a duplicate question. I have read the other questions concerning read-only Excel documents and they do not apply.

Comment: Linking to these 'do not apply' questions & explaining in more detail what happens, what version of Office, what Mac & macOS etc  would save duplicated effort.

Comment: Additionally, where is the file being saved, local storage, network storage, a USB flash drive?

Comment: Is Autosave enabled?